# forzar mi website que no aparezca con 'www'

Tags: redirección

Quisiera forzar a mi web que no se muestre en el navegador con las **'www'**
o sea https://miweb.com
He intentado en el htaccess con

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.miweb.com$  
RewriteRule (.*) https://miweb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Pero no funciona ya que la pongo con 'www' y se muestra igual.
Como nota a tener en cuenta dire que mi web es un script de PHP (No CMS)
Alguna sugerencia ?

Comment: ¿No sería más fácil hacer un redirect a nivel de dominio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vi que en la parte de `RewriteRule (.*) ETC,ETC` no si podría ser por que falta el símbolo `^` al principio y el símbolo `$` al final.

(no tengo muchos conocimientos sobre el uso de htaccess)

Podrías probar de la siguiente forma:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.miweb.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://miweb.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hola Gracias por responder, pero no me redirecciona sin las 'www' con lo que añadiste. Es practicamente igual.

Comment: Gracias ya lo arregle, tuve que entrar en mi server: - www.miweb.com
- miweb.com
- Ninguno  De esta manera lo he forzado ahi